# Difference between count = count + n&1 and count += n&1

Tags: c++14, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am writing a program in which I want to calculate set bits in an integer.
For eg, if 5 can be written as 0101 where a number of set bits is 2.
However, when I executed the program where I wrote **count = count + n & 1** It didn't work but if I change that to **count += n&1** it worked totally fine, and I couldn't find any reason for that

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int n = 5;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while(n){

      //count += n&1;
        count = count + n & 1;
        n>>=1;
    }
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the *operator precedence* of + (binary) and & (binary)? Why does this not affect the += form? How can the expanded form be updated (with grouping operators) to ensure the same/expected result? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence , which also has links to relevant compound assignment documentation..

Comment: The problem of your code is the precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence in C++ or any other programming languages determines the order of evaluation of those instructions, some go from right to left, some are evaluated first before the other. So, in this case, your += was evaluated after the & (AND) operator, and that was the reason for your wrong answer when is done this way

```
count = count + n & 1;
```

Because in the code above, the + is evaluated then the AND was then next. You can either put a bracket around it like this below

```
count = count + (n & 1);
```

Since the bracket operator has higher precedence it will always ensure you get the right results. 
You can learn more about precedence [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Operators-Precedence-in-Cplusplus). You will see the order of evaluation for each operator.

> The associativity of an operator is a property that determines how
>   operators of the same precedence are grouped in the absence of
>   parentheses. This affects how an expression is evaluated.

And you can always check your C++ or C reference Manuals to learn more about precedence.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Precedence says nothing about *order* of evaluation; that's something very different.

Comment: The ones with the higher precedence are evaluated first, like the logical not operator, then the parenthesis or bracket operator, and so on to the last.

Comment: No, that's not true: precedence makes little difference to order of execution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> Operators are evaluated from top to bottom of the list. Those at the
>   top are evaluated first, and those below are evaluated last according
>   to their associativity either left to right or right to left.